# Some problems while I am building tensorflow

Tags: python, bazel

I cannot build tensorflow on my system. My configuration:

```
system:ubuntu16.04
cuda:gtx1070
cudnn:6.0    
cuda:8.0    
tensorflow version:1.3.1    
python:3.5.3(install in the workspace of pyenv)    
bazel version:0.5.2    
gcc version:5.4.0
```

When I run:

```
./configure
bazel build --config-opt --config-cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package --verbose_failures
```

then it crashes with missing crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc file in the cuda repository:
[image]

The content of generated `.tf_configure_bazelrc` is:

```
build --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/root/.pyenv/shims/python"
build --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
build --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/root/.pyenv/shims/python"
build --define PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
build --force_python=py3
build --host_force_python=py3
build --python3_path="/root/.pyenv/shims/python"
test --force_python=py3
test --host_force_python=py3
test --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/root/.pyenv/shims/python"
test --define PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
run --define PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/root/.pyenv/shims/python"
run --define PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/root/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages"
build --define with_jemalloc=true
build:opt --cxxopt=-march=native --copt=-march=native
build --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA="1"
build --action_env TF_NEED_OPENCL="0"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_CLANG="0"
build --action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH="/usr/local/cuda"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_VERSION="8.0"
build --action_env GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH="/usr/bin/gcc"
build --action_env TF_CUDNN_VERSION="6"
build --action_env CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-8.0"
build --action_env TF_CUDNN_VERSION="6"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES="6.1"
build --config=cuda
test --config=cuda
```

Comment: Please avoid posting screenshots with code/logs, it makes copy-pasting hard.

Answer (score 1):

It's complaining that it cannot find `crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc` 
 file, which is a wrapper for C++ complier. I'd try updating bazel to version 0.6.0. Can you rerun with `--sandbox_debug`, and ideally manually inspect the generated sandbox directory if it contains `crosstool_wrapper_driver_is_not_gcc`, if permissions are set correctly, and if you can manually  execute the command that bazel is trying to execute.